# Google Analytics for Firebase event parameter data type change

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I initially setup a firebase event parameter, say "param1", to be a Text data type because the it contained a leading character in front of 4 numbers.  After realizing Firebase severely limits the number of parameters that can be of type "Text" I stripped off the leading character (as it didn't add any value to me) and changed the data type to "Number" (Standard).  However, after doing that I don't see "param1" values in my event, even after several days. I assume this is because some of the data for param1 previous had a leading character and therefore can't be displayed as a Number.  Any idea how long I will need to wait until Firebase no longer has any param1 data values with the leading character?

Comment: Hey, do you remember how long did you have to wait? Did it fix itself eventually or did you find another way?